# How to bypass undefined (reading 'src') using jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you bypass undefined (reading 'src') within a jquery $.each format.

I have about 100 products that some have images and some don't.

Using jquery $.ajax I am able to get the response. then I use the response in $.each format as per below

```
 $.each(response, function (i, item) {
    console.log(item);  
    
   var gmi = item.images[0].src; 
    
    
    });
```

The above code works for products with an image and limit to 1 in the ajax call.
However, when I lift the limit and load in all products (including those without images) the same code throws an error and page doesn't build.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'src')

I've tried the following codes below creating a var to change the src and have even use .lenght  to try and by pass it, but had no success.

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
console.log(item);  

if(item.images =="undefined"){
var gmi = "no image applied";} 
else {var gmi = item.images[0].src;}


});
```

OR

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
console.log(item);  
 
var img = item.images;         
    img.lenght;     
if(img ===0){
var gmi = "no image applied";} 
else {var gmi = item.images[0].src;}


});
```

In the item array. those products with images have **item.images[0].src** and those without have **item.images**, the **item.images** because  it empty is causing my headache.

So is it possible to bypass when the image object has no "src" ?

Kind regrads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at optional chaining
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
var gmi = item?.images[0]?.src;
```

Comment: Thank you , on the money, headache over.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in the second code. Did you mean?

```
var img = img.length;
```

Comment: Yes meant  var img = img.length;  thank you for  your replay.